# How i can avoid a repetition in my java resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, architecture

I modified my ".classpath" file to change this line

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
```

for

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
```

to have the good architecture for a Maven project...

Now in my sources i have a sort of recursion :
[image: my problem]

On the top Java Resources it's now good, but not in the bottom Java Resources where I have a repetition :

I'm supposed to have only :

- com.douineau

But i have also

- com
- com.com.douineau

I hope anybody can help me.

Thank u in advance

Comment: Manual changes to `.classpath` are unnecessary and probably a bad idea. Just  create or convert the project to Maven and Eclipse will do the rest automatically.

Comment: I did so, and Eclipse created the resources line  "<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>" but didn't change the java line...

Comment: @JosselinDouineau why should the java line being changed? Learn that if you use Maven the truth is Maven not your IDE anymore...